# Javascript functions - deciphering the documentation about basic functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have been trying to learn javascript for years. I've done at least 10 code camps, udemy courses and a few weekend sessions. I still don't have an answer to makes sense of why, in this example, a does not equal the value outside the function?

It's not called within the function statement. And inside the function, it's not defined as a var at all.  If b has its value from outside the function, then why does a use the var b defined inside the function when it is called outside the function?

Where is a reference to decipher these documents?

> This is semantically equivalent to the `function avg()` form. It's extremely powerful, as it lets you put a full function definition anywhere that you would normally put an expression.  This enables all sorts of clever tricks. Here's a way of "hiding" some local variables -- like block scope in C:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

(function() {
  var b = 3;
  a += b;
})();

a; // 4
b; // 2
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - this picture is taken from the Mozilla documents.

Comment: @Daniel_Beck - please put the picture back. It includes commentary about what the example is trying to do. The commentary makes no sense. That's why I'm asking for help. It's so weird why editors assume what is a good question - I'm struggling to make sense of the documentation explaining things.

Comment: @Mel Do it yourself?  We don't accept image of code or of any other textual thing, except if the poster **also** includes its transcription. Daniel has been kind enough to make a part of that transcription, it is your job to do it all.

Comment: I did not notice the image included extra text, I will reintroduce that into the question. Apologies.

Comment: @Kaiido - i added the transcription myself!

Comment: @DanielBeck - thanks

Comment: Then you should have done it correctly directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` controls the scope of the variable; because "b" is redeclared as a var inside the closure, it's actually a new variable (which happens to share the same name as the "b" variable outside the closure.)  "a" is not re-declared with "var", so inside the closure "a" continues to refer to the global variable "a".

```
var a = 1;  // Global "a"
var b = 2;  // Global "b"

(function() {
  var b = 3; // "var" indicates a new "b" variable, declared inside the closure.   
             // The local "b" masks the global "b" while inside the closure.
  a += b;    // Global "a" (1) added to local "b" (3)
})();

a; // 4   (global "a")
b; // 2   (global "b", still 2, because the in-closure "b" is no longer in scope)
```

This is, of course, confusing.  For this reason, it's generally a good idea to use differently-named variables at each scope level rather than depending on masking as in the code example above.  Whatever source you've found that describes this sort of thing as a "clever trick" should be ignored with prejudice.

Comment: so if you want to make a global inside a function, you do it without declaring it using any of the declaration words available (var, let const)? Where is that in the rule book?

Comment: but what is it reassigned as? not a variable? just something? that has no name?

Comment: you can't make a global variable in a  non-global scope.  Nothing's being reassigned; you just have two different variables that happen to both be named "b".

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating a new variable inside the function (note the use of `var`). It would be the same as if you had written

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

(function() {
    var someOtherName = 3;
    a += someOtherName;
})();
```

It just happened that the variable outside the function had the same name as the variable inside the function. They were completely separate variables with no relation other than they were given the same name. `a` had 3 added to it because that's the value that the local variable `b` had. The local `b` "shadowed" the global `b`.

Comment: so why did the first one get ignored?

Comment: @Mel Because of "shadowing". If you create a local variable with the same name as a more global one, the local one is preferred.

Comment: @Kaiido Whoops, "name" should say "value". That's an odd typo.

Comment: @Kaiido I was trying to point out that creating a new variable wasn't necessary, but I think that detracted from the main point. I just removed the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are thinking this correctly. When you make a new instanciation of B inside the function, the outside B is ignored (but this only works inside the function).

Since you are using A from outside the function to sum with the B inside the function, you get 4 (1 + 3) for A. In other hand, B still 2 looking from outside.